# Echo HTML Into Text File

Tags: echo

Is there a simple way to echo some HTML code into a text/HTML file?

I'm trying to do:

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Hello World!</h1>\n\t</body>\n</html>" > index.html
```

But get:

```
-bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote as bash interprets `!` as a special char

Also, use `-e` with `echo` so that the backslash escapes like `\n` are interpreted

```
echo -e '<html>\n<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Hello World!</h1>\n\t</body>\n</html>' > index.html
```

Comment: That depends on how bash was built. In  the bash of Solaris 11.4 for instance, `\x` sequences are expanded by default and `echo -e` outputs `-e` (as POSIX currently requires). [Use `printf` instead to get a consistent behaviour](/q/65803).

Comment: Thanks for the extra tidbit about using -e, which is important since I'm using \n and \t.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using single quotes instead of double-quotes. So, this should work as expected -

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Hello World!</h1>\n\t</body>\n</html>' > index.html
```

When you use single quotes, bash doesn’t try to interpret special characters and simply preserves the literal string.

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering a history expansion in `bash` with `!`.  Either turn off history expansions with `set +H`, use a single quoted string, or use a here-document to write your HTML:

```
$ cat <<'END_HTML' >index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <body>
                <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </body>
</html>
END_HTML
```

Or, if you want to write out those encoded tabs and newlines as they are:

```
$ cat <<'END_HTML' >index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Hello World!</h1>\n\t</body>\n</html>
END_HTML
```

History expansions are not triggered within here-documents in `bash`.